# Shapeless: UnaryTCConstraint for Foo[T, U]

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have the following working as expected:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.UnaryTCConstraint._
import shapeless.test.illTyped

case class Foo[R](result: R, dependencies: Set[Foo[_]] = Set.empty)

//This method only accepts an HList of Foo
def method[L <: HList](list: L)(implicit utcc: UnaryTCConstraint[L, Foo]) = println("checks")

val notFoos = "abc" :: 1 :: 5.5 :: HNil
illTyped { """method(notFoos)""" }

val aFoo = Foo("abc")
val bFoo = Foo(2, Set(aFoo))
val cFoo = Foo(true, Set(bFoo))
val onlyFoos = aFoo :: bFoo :: cFoo :: HNil
method(onlyFoos) // prints checks
```

After some refactoring I've came to the conclusion that dependencies should be a HList of Foos. So I changed the code to:

```
type FooWithAnyDependency[R] = Foo[R, _ <: HList]

case class Foo[R, L <: HList](result: R, dependencies: L = HNil)(implicit utcc: UnaryTCConstraint[L, FooWithAnyDependency])

def method2[L <: HList](list: L)(implicit utcc: UnaryTCConstraint[L, FooWithAnyDependency]) = println("checks")
```

This code compiles, however when I try to use it:

```
val aFoo = Foo("abc")
```

I get this error:

```
Could not find implicit value for parameter utcc: shapeless.UnaryTCConstraint[shapeless.HNil.type,FooWithAnyDependency]
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
val aFoo = Foo("abc")
               ^
```

I think its failing because its trying to find an UnaryTCConstraint[HNil **.type**, FooWithAnyDependency].

I know that implementing a custom Constraint will solve the problem (I've already done it), however I run into the same problem whenever I try to use something else, for example: `Comapped.Aux[L, FooWithAnyDependency, M]`.

So the question is, how can I overcome this problem without having to re-implement most things just for Foo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exactly right that the issue is the inferred `HNil.type` singleton type. Fortunately the fix is very straightforward—you just provide a type annotation for `HNil`:

```
case class Foo[R, L <: HList](
  result: R,
  dependencies: L = HNil: HNil
)(implicit utcc: UnaryTCConstraint[L, FooWithAnyDependency])
```

In general when working with Shapeless you'll need to provide a type annotation like this for `HNil` to avoid the (more or less useless) singleton type `HNil.type`, except when you write something like this:

```
val hlist = 1 :: HNil
```

Which will have the inferred type `Int :: HNil` instead of `Int :: HNil.type` only because `HNil` has a `::` method that ensures that you get the right type.

Comment: This works `val aFoo = Foo("abc")` but this `val bFoo = Foo(5, aFoo :: HNil)` doesn't. The error is: `could not find implicit value for parameter utcc: shapeless.UnaryTCConstraint[shapeless.::[Foo[String,HNil],HNil], FooWithAnyDependency]`. I can't understand why.

Comment: @SimãoMartins Looks like a unification issue. I'd suggest writing your own type class to capture the constraint.